# PDF fit half page

Tags: pdf, scrolling

I have a PDF file containing slides, but the document has been created with two horizontal slides per (portrait) page (yes, a "handouts format")

I want to be able to scroll pages using page Up/page Down, but unfortunately the "fit size" option in pdf viewers will fit the whole page with the two slides. It's written too small and it's uncomfortable to read.

Is there a way to resplit the pdf with one slide per page, or to find a very convenient way to scroll half a page at a time with page Up/Down (and it scrolls EXACTLY half a page, otherwise it's super annoying)

**EDIT**
I don't own the source file unfortunately, and I'm running most on the time on Windows using Foxit Reader or Lumin PDF for the Drive

**EDIT 2** **EDIT 3**

[3 pages Sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8EhxTyDP6M-RVBzOVV3dUVwTWs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You might want to add your OS to the question in case there are solutions available in one OS but not another.  Also, do you own the source file (in which case, you could reformat and re-export to PDF)?  Does the PDF contain the source document elements, or is it something like scans of hard copy stored as PDF?

Comment: What is the nature of the content -- does it contain the source document elements or is it images of 2-slide pages like a scanned hardcopy?  If the individual slides still exist in the PDF, you could use something like http://smallpdf.com/, which is a handy online utility for doing a variety of PDF manipulations, to convert the file to editable form, or extract the slide images, and then export a new PDF formatted as you want.

Comment: I tried the PDF to PPT tool of smallpdf.com, but unfortunately, it won't put one slide per page, but rather will put the content of 2 slides in one "A4" slide, just as in the original document (which I extracted with smallpdf which is really nice btw).

The pdf contains text and images, as well as drawings, tables, etc. I'll upload a sample (just the first page)

Comment: I'm guessing this is a "handouts" output (puts images of several sildes per page for distributing the presentation).  In the converted PPT, can you select individual slide images or is the entire page one image?  Without the actual file, there's no way to experiment, but two things to try: 1) If the slides are individual images, try resizing the page to half the height (force page breaks).  2) Create a new presentation and paste one slide image to each new slide.  If the slides aren't individual images, zoom the page so one slide fills the screen and do an area capture.

Comment: I want an automated/fast way to do this. Let's say I have thousands of pages like this, I don't want to bother spending 3 minutes trying to capture/paste each slide just for "better readability".
The sample I uploaded corresponds exactly to what I have, except I have many more slides. I don't have any mean of getting the original ppt(s).

I'll save the "4 slides per landscape page" for another time :P

Comment: I'm guessing this would require some type of script, or a batch command using something like Irfanview.  1st step, split the pages into top half and bottom half with a naming convention that retains the sequence.  2nd step, select all images and convert to a slide show.  Often, these kinds of one-time conversion jobs can be more work than they're worth.

Comment: Yeah, that's why a simple adjust-zoom-so-it-works would be nice, IF we can get a nice way to do it. For example, find a way to get the view size, and compute the % of zoom that would show exactly 1/2 page

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me using your sample file:

I opened the file with Adobe Reader and I simply clicked on "adjust to window width" (which I roughly translated myself :D). This openend the PDF at 130% and made it readable. You can also use Page up and down this way.

I'll add a screenshot just in case (the red circle is the "adjust width option" I was talking about.

http://postimg.org/image/lfd46iufj/

Comment: So your solution addresses how to view the original file one slide at a time rather than creating a new file with one slide per page?  Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best.

Comment: Yeah, you *could* try to resize the window so that exactly the middle of one page would fit. But then if it is not EXACTLY the middle, after a few slides, it will desynchronize.

I only gave a one page sample, so it's not easy to realize, but even on your screenshot, you can see the beginning of the next slide, which means that when you'll press pagedown, you will scroll to the last 6/10 or the first page + the 1/10  of the next page, and it will get worse for future slides

Comment: I reuploaded a 3 pages version so you can actually see how it happens after you scroll 2 pages. I'm totally fine with a solution like yours, as long as it's easy/short to parameterize. If I need to spend several dozens of minutes trying to figure out the optimal window size/zoom so it scrolls exactly 1/2 page, knowing I have to do this everytime I change the window size... I'm not taking it.

Comment: I understand what you mean. The quickest solution I know is repeating this process: Page down, ctrl + page down, page down, ctrl + page down. etc. 

It's not a perfect solution but maybe this works for the meantime. Maybe I think of something better, but I can't guarantee that :P

Comment: What is CTRL + Pagedown supposed to do ? I'm not using Adobe Reader.

Comment: Ctrl + pagedown takes you to the top of the next page. This helps against the desynchronization you were talking about.